# JDBC PreparedStatement with Hexadecimal Literals

Tags: mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement, hex

I have a Mysql compatible Hexadecimal Literal, for example X'4D7953514C'
How do I assign such a value with PreparedStatments, I tried setString but the value gets wrapped into quotes.

The goal is to have a sql statement that looks like this (col1 is a varchar):

```
insert into t1 (col1) values (x'4D7953514C');
```

Comment: Well you are setting a string... I mean if you are inserting a hex string into a string field it is a string. This question is confusing you are trying to insert a string into a string and dont want it to be a string? Please reformulate your question a little bit better.

Comment: I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set hexadecimal strings like `x'4D7953514C'` directly using JDBC. You either need to use `setString()` with the actual intended value (`MySQL`), or use `setBytes()` with a byte array with the right values (eg `new byte[] {0x4D, 0x79, 0x53, 0x51, 0x4C }`, although I am not 100% sure this works with MySQL Connector/J).

The `X'...'` is the SQL syntax for binary literals. When you are using parametrized queries you aren't using literals, you are using parameters, so the literal syntax does not apply.